# Getting env data in vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How can I have `.env` data such as `APP_NAME` in my components?

Let say I want to show to users `Welcome to {{APP_NAME}}`

## UPDATE

Base on [this document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables) I've made changes in my env file and like:

```
MIX_APP_NAME=Laravel
```

and added this to my component script:

```
data() {
  return {
    app_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME,
  }
},
```

Now I can have my app name in my component but the issue is I want to use it in bootstrap tooltip and there gives me this error:

```
- title=".... by {{app_name}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
```

My code:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="... {{app_name}}"></span>
```

Any idea?

Comment: title="\`text ${app_name}\`"

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько it doesn't give error but also print like `${app_name}` in my view

Comment: sorry: `:title="\`text ${app_name}\`"`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько that will do it :) please share it as answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add to env file:

```
MIX_APP_NAME=Laravel
```

and add this to your component script:

```
data() {
  return {
    app_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME,
  }
},
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
 <div :title="`text ${app_name}`"></div>
```

Or:

```
{{ app_name }}
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables)

Comment: thats worked for me without any require in webpack.mix ... just add a new variable in env file with this prefix : MIX_  but need to restart php artisan serve and also restart npm run watch....

Answer (score 2):

thats worked for me without adding any require in webpack.mix

... just add a new variable in env file with this prefix : MIX_

**BUT** need to **restart** with `php artisan serve` and also restart with `npm run watch` ....

Comment: Restarting everything did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 10.x:

You may inject environment variables into your JavaScript by prefixing them with VITE_ in your application's **.env** file:

```
VITE_APP_NAME=http://example.com
```

You may access injected environment variables via the **import.meta.env** object:

```
import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME
```

You can find the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use it as `process.env.APP_NAME`

```
mounted(){
   this.appName=process.env.APP_NAME
}
```

Comment: i found this as well https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables but it gives error on `npm run watch`

Comment: Are you using vue-cli?

Comment: How are you setting the variable in environment,  maybe you are setting it in wrong way.

Comment: `MIX_APP_NAME=Laravel`

Comment: Updated my question please check it